# How does the QRect works?

Tags: c++, qt, rectangles

```
std::vector<QPoint> points;
points.push_back({3, 1});
points.push_back({6, 1});
points.push_back({6, 4});
points.push_back({3, 4});

QRect rect(points[0], QSize{points[1].x() - points[0].x(), points[2].y() - points[1].y()});

qDebug() << rect << rect.topLeft() << rect.topRight() << rect.bottomRight() << rect.bottomLeft() << rect.width() << rect.height();
```

The above prints:

```
QRect(3,1 3x3) QPoint(3,1) QPoint(5,1) QPoint(5,3) QPoint(3,3) 3 3
```

The above seems strange to me. It seems `(6,1)` is shifted to `(5.1)`. And a similar thing happened to other positions.

How is width `3`? Isn't it supposed to be `5 - 3` (topright - topleft)?

From [QRect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html) documentation:

> There is a third constructor that creates a QRect using the top-left and bottom-right coordinates, but we recommend that you avoid using it. The rationale is that for historical reasons the values returned by the bottom() and right() functions deviate from the true bottom-right corner of the rectangle.

Which doesn't clarify it to me.

Comment: The width is `points[1].x() - points[0].x()`, which is `6 - 3`, which is `3`.

Comment: The width being `3` makes sense. But how can that topRight be `5`?

Comment: Positions like these are usually zero-based, like array indexes. So the rectangle goes from position `3`, through `4` and to `5`.

Comment: The Qt docs say: *"The right() function returns left() + width() - 1 ..."*, i.e. `3 + 3 - 1 = 5`.

Comment: `QRect` is typically used when dealing with pixel coordinates. If you have a rectangle whose left most pixel is at pixel coordinate 3 and has a width of 3 pixels, the right most pixel will be on pixel coordinate 5. You may be interested in `QRectF` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`QRect::right()` tries to return last pixel that's yet inside the rectangle's surface, for example:

```
int right = rect.left() + rect.width() - 1;

Q_ASSERT(rect.right() == right);
```

Of course, `QRect::bottom()` works similarly.

If such behaviour is not desired, then you can either use `QRectF` class instead, or always manually do:

```
int right = rect.left() + rect.width();
```